# Kurdish font using tcpdf library not working

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf, right-to-left, arabic-support

Useing this code kurdish text not display correctly in pdf.

```
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
require_once('../tcpdf_import.php');
require_once('../tcpdf.php');


$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('PACRA');

$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('../fonts/majalla.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

// use the font
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', true);

//$pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 10);
//font arabic


$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'ar'; // 'arabic' for Arabic
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

// set font
//$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$d=" شركة عمرو وكوبري للاقمشة ";
$xd=" توانا أسعد تەها , رۆژانە پێسویتمان بە ئاو خواردنەو هەیە بۆ گەدە چونکە ڤارا ژەهرە بۆ ڕیازهی چارە پارە ";

 

$pdf->SetXY(3, 5);   

$pdf->Cell(11,5,$xd,0);

$pdf->Output('hello_world_in_Arabic.pdf', 'I');
```

I tried all kurdish font list [from](https://www.kurdfonts.com/browse/kurdfonts-unicode-set-3)

> this text
> توانا أسعد تەها , رۆژانە **پێسویتمان** بە ئاو خواردنەو هەیە بۆ گەدە چونکە ڤارا ژەهرە بۆ ڕیازهی چارە پارە
> result in pdf look like ,
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLmab.jpg)